# Oracle PIVOT selective rows to columns

Tags: oracle, pivot

Thanks in Advance ....!!!

I am looking to PIVOT two amount fields into multiple columns based on a column e.g. PIVOT_NAME
I have multiple other fields that act as BK which will remain as row 
BK Columns: BKCOL1,DEPT,YEAR_PD,TRANS_DATE
e.g. INPUT

```
BKCOL1  DEPT    YEAR_PD TRAN_DATE   PIVOT_NAME  TY_SALES    LY_SALES
100_bk  D1      2020002 2019-10-11  P1         -1           1
100_bk  D1      2020002 2019-10-12  P2         -2           2
100_bk  D1      2020002 2019-10-11  P3         -3           3
100_bk  D1      2020002 2019-10-14  P4         -4           4
100_bk  D2      2020002 2019-10-14  P1         -5           5
100_bk  D2      2020002 2019-10-16  P2         -7           7
100_bk  D2      2020002 2019-10-17  P3         -8           8
100_bk  D2      2020002 2019-10-18  P5         -9           9
```

Adding Input table image as well

[INPUT TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqApZ.png)

Expected OUTPUT:
[Expected OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lofK5.png)

All TY% fields are populated from `TY_SALES`
All LY% Fields are populated from `LY_SALES`
and based on `PIVOT_NAME`
i.e if ``PIVOT_NAME = P1 then i want to populate `TY_P1_SALES` and `LY_P1_SALES` and so on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `pivot` gives desired output:

```
select bkcol1, dept, year_pd, tran_date, 
       p1_ty, p2_ty, p3_ty, p4_ty, p5_ty,
       p1_ly, p2_ly, p3_ly, p4_ly, p5_ly
  from input
  pivot (sum(ty_sales) ty, sum(ly_sales) ly for pivot_name in ('P1' p1, 'P2' p2, 'P3' p3, 'P4' p4, 'P5' p5))
  order by dept, tran_date
```

**<sup>[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6d8eeebf3a208b24a8a7cf91fc0dde98)</sup>**

Add aliases for the columns if you want the others.